# Disable option for USB accessories

Tags: iphone, usb, security, accessories

I have an iPhone SE.

I want to disable USB Accessories so that my phone cannot be connected to via USB after an hour, protecting my security.

The problem I have is that the option is enabled, and I cannot disable it because it is greyed out, preventing me from tapping on it. I checked a few YouTube tutorial videos and it just seems to work.

Comment: click the lock icon and enter your administrator username/password, you can then make changes

Comment: @SteveChambers Where is the lock icon?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the switch? If It's greyed out, then that normally indicates that it is off. You should have to enter your PIN to access the Touch ID settings page. Which SE and which iOS version?

Comment: No, it is enabled in green, but slightly grey. To access that page I entered my alphanumeric password. It might be because it is a company phone which has access controls? It is the most recent iPhone SE and the most recent update (software version 15.4.1).